# Optional override multi value with environment variable in typesafe config library

Tags: java, typesafe-config

I like the [typesafe config lib](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) but I have not yet figured out if and how it would be possible to optionally override certain multi values.

Something like this

```
multi = [
  "string"
  "list"
]
multi=${?MULTI_ENV}
```

But this way (if the environment variable `MULTI_ENV` is set to e.g. `"value1,value2"` or `"value1 value2"`) of course the `ConfigFactory.load().resolve().getStringList("multi")` throws an exception, because multi is a simple `String` now.

I have tried `multi=[${?MULTI_ENV}]` too, but this does not do the trick either, because in case that the `MULTI_ENV` variable is not set `multi` will be empty.

It does not seem to be possible without some additional code which would check the environment variable, parsing it to a `List<String>` by hand and override the value manually `config.withValue("multi",myParsedStringList)`, or is it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like as of today there is built in feature for this.

A [feature request](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/issues/320) exists since May 2015 but it is unlikely to be implemented because environment variables are not treated as having syntax.

[System properties already support something similar](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/issues/69) with numeric keys to lists:

```
-Dfoo1=bar -Dfoo2=BAZ
```